# Load More Button Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, button

I have implemented a Load more button using Angular and Typescript I want to view 6 posts at the starting and then once I click on it another 6 posts be shown the button is working but, all posts are hidden unless I click on the button.I attached the html code and the typescript as well.
Please advise.
Thanks

HTML

```
    `<button mat-button *ngIf="isMore" color="accent" class="load-more-container" (click)="onMore()">Load
    more</button>`
```

TypeScript

```
  import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Input,
} from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { BlogDetails, BlogResponse } from "../models/blog";
import { BlogService } from "../services/blog.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthService } from "../../../../providers/auth.service";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../../../../services/authentication.service";
import { SignupComponent } from "../../../../pages/authentication/signup/signup.component";

@Component({
  selector: "anms-blog-list",
  templateUrl: "./blog-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./blog-list.component.scss"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class BlogListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() agentFirstName: string;
  @Input() agentLastName: string;
  @Input() agendId: string;
  @Input() agentType: string;
  @Input() agentEmail: string;
  @Input() firstName: string;
  @Input() lastName: string;
  blogs: BlogDetails[];
  blogArray$: Observable<BlogDetails[]>;
  blogOutput$: Observable<BlogDetails[]>;
  // paginatorEnabled: boolean;
  moreData: any;
  limit = 1;
  isMore = true;
  isLimit: number;
  blogData: BlogDetails[];
  constructor(
    private blogService: BlogService,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.paginatorEnabled = true;
    this.blogArray$ = this.blogService.getBlogs();
    // this.blogOutput$ = this.blogService.firstPaginate();
    // this.blogOutput$.subscribe(blog => {
    //   this.blogs = blog as BlogDetails[];
    // });
    this.getData();
  }
  getData(){
    this.blogService.getBlogs().subscribe(res=>{
      this.blogData=res;
      this.moreData = this.blogData.slice(0, this.limit * 6);
      console.log(this.blogData)
      console.log(this.moreData)
    })
  }
  navigateBlog(id: string) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/blogs/" + id);
  }
  editBlog(id: string) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/blogs/edit/" + id);
  }
  onChangePage() {
  //  this.blogOutput$ = this.blogService.paginateNext();
  //  this.questionsOutput$.subscribe((question) => {
  //    this.questions = question as Question[];
   // });

//if (this.questions.length === this.previousLength)
    //  this.paginatorEnabled = false;
    //this.previousLength = this.questions.length;
   // this.moreData = this.questions.slice(0, this.limit * 6);
  }

  onMore() {
   this.isLimit = this.blogData.length - 6 * this.limit;
    this.limit += 1;
    this.getData();
    if (this.isLimit > 6) {
      this.isMore = true;
    } else {
      this.isMore = false;
    }
  }

  createBlog() {
    // if (this.isUserLoggedIn) {
    //   this.router.navigateByUrl('/blogs/add');
    // } else {
    //   this.authenticationService.showSignUp(SignupComponent, {
    //     isAgent: null,
    //     redirect: '/blogs/add',
    //     userAutoLoginAfterSignUp: true
    //   });
    // }
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/blogs/add");
  }
  get agentName() {
    return this.agentFirstName + " " + this.agentLastName;
  }

  get isUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.authService.isCurrentSession;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a static array for blogs or are the blogs coming from an api? If it's an API you might want to implement pagination on the server side then on click of the button you call the api with updated paging parameters the append the result to the existing array.

Comment: The blogs are coming through Strapi CMS and the total number of Blogs is unknown as they can be added anytime.

Comment: From  the [Strapi docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#start]) you could us the start and limit query parameters to implement paging. I can see the default  result count is 100. I can see the provide a separate endpoint to get the total count in case you need to use the count. There's probably a better way they could return the paging information but what they have can also work. You also want to post the HTML part where you are looping through the blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your html code where in you are iterating over the blogData.

Based on what you have provided, from ngOnit you are calling the getBlogs service twice, any particular reason?

In your html code, are you subscribing to this.blogArray$ using an async pipe? Are you also using this.blogData and this.moreData in your html template?